# Clone Div elements and attach events to new elements

Tags: php, jquery

I have drop down boxes related to each other. The second dropdown values are filtered according to first dropdown box value.

Now I want to clone elements in div with class="old_div" into div with class="new_div" and add events to each new elements in div with class="new_div".

ADD

---

```
    <div class="old_div" >
    <select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="1">Fruit</option>
    <option value="2">Animal</option>
    <option value="3">Bird</option>
    <option value="4">Car</option>
    </select>


    <select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option value="1">Banana</option>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="1">Orange</option>
    <option value="2">Wolf</option>
    <option value="2">Fox</option>
    <option value="2">Bear</option>
    <option value="3">Eagle</option>
    <option value="3">Hawk</option>
    <option value="4">BWM</option>
    </select>

        <br />
    </div>

    <div class="new_div">


    </div>
```

I am able to clone elements to new div using Jquery

Jquery code:

```
$("#add_a").on('click',function(){
    var data = $('.old_div').html();
    $('.new_div').append(data);
});

$("#select1").on('change', function() { 
if($(this).data('options') == undefined){

$(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
} 
var id = $(this).val().trim();
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
$('#select2').html(options);
});
```

But how can i make new elements to be related to each other.

I have created fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6YEQx/ for reference.

Comment: I think your question needs more clarification. Are you cloning the elements and just want them to have an event or do you also want the <select>..</select> dropdowns to be inside the new_div too.

Comment: HI, I am able to add <select>..</select> dropdowns into new_div. But i also want to have event to each new elements inside new_div.

Comment: What is the event you want to bind to second select? Does it vary on first select or only second one? Can you give some more information?

Comment: Current code produces invalid markup **because of id duplication**.

Comment: HI, if you can refer my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6YEQx/, you can see that if you select "ANIMAL" with value as "2" from first dropdown, the second dropdown lists options with values only with "2". Now when ever i create new elements the same event should repeat for each. Say i create second set of dropdown box and select "BIRD" with value "3" the second dropdown box corresponding to second set should list values only with "3" and so on...

Comment: HI Jai, I have updated my fiddle to have <select>..</select> with class attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `id` with select box and making duplicates of it, this is causing problem to identify select box using `id` in jQuery. So use `class` instead of `id`.

HTML :

```
<select name="select1" class="select1">
  <option value="1">Fruit</option>
  <option value="2">Animal</option>
  <option value="3">Bird</option>
  <option value="4">Car</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" class="select2">
  <option value="1">Banana</option>
  <option value="1">Apple</option>
  <option value="1">Orange</option>
  <option value="2">Wolf</option>
  <option value="2">Fox</option>
  <option value="2">Bear</option>
  <option value="3">Eagle</option>
  <option value="3">Hawk</option>
  <option value="4">BWM</option>
</select>
```

Also you are adding elements dynamically so need to bind change event using `$(document)` and `on`.

**EDIT**: also added new line in add_a button script to show all options in second select box initially.

jQuery :

```
  $("#add_a").on('click',function(){
        var data = $('.old_div').html();
        $('.new_div').append(data);
        // to show all options initially and remove any preselected option
        $('.new_div').find('.select2:last option').show().removeAttr('selected');
    });

$(document).on('change',".select1", function() { 
    var id = $(this).val().trim();
    $(this).next('.select2').find('option').hide();
    var $options = $(this).next('.select2').find('option[value=' + id + ']');
   $options.show();
   $options.first().attr('selected',true)
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6YEQx/38/)**

Comment: Hi Bhushan, Thanks for the quick solution. This meets my requirement. Thank you once again..

Comment: @user1796743, I have edited `add_a` button click event script to show all options for second select box when added dynamically. Suppose you have selected `Car` in first select box and then click on ADD button. Then newly added `select2` box will show `BMW` but `select1` has fruit selected. To remove this problem I updated my answer and demo link. Please check.

Comment: Hi Bhushan, Again Thanks for the update.. But can you let me know how to add blank select option (i.e <option value=""></option>) to second dropdown of each element.

Comment: You can add it for first select1 and select2 options on page load. And it will reflects in newly added automatically. Use `$('select').prepend('<option value="" selected></option>');` at first line of `$(function(){..` see this http://jsfiddle.net/6YEQx/42/  And if you want to put this blank option for select1/ select2 only then just change jquery selector like this `$('.select1').prepen` or  `$('.select2').prepen`

Comment: HI Bhushan, Out of curiosity i am asking. can same be achieved if the second element is checkbox instead of dropdown box?? Pease see my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q7Htk/

Comment: That was nice, but cant we hide/delete other elements except the ones that are checked?? I have updated fiddle, but i am not able to hide/remove other elements.